# How do you save a page by button click on page exit using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have tried just about everything i can think of to trigger a button which triggers the save page event on page exit yet it never fires.  I want the event to fire whether the button is visible or not on page exit.  The new security measures on chrome, firefox etc do not allow you to modify the page exit command popup.

here is my code that does not fire

```
   window.onbeforeunload = check();

function check() {
    var response = confirm("Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
    
    if(response == true)
    {
         var btn = document.getElementById("<%= btnTest.ClientID %>");
                 btn.click();
    }
}
```

if i take the

```
var btn = document.getElementById("<%= btnTest.ClientID %>");
                     btn.click();
```

out and put it onLoad it fires so i know it isnt the button that isnt firing.

Or is there no way to to save a page on exit anymore?

asp.net
C#

Comment: Is the button visible? Remember, any control marked with visible=false means that control is NEVER sent to the client side browser. So, if you want that button or control to be rendered, then use style="display:none", since setting visible = false means the control is not sent nor rendered in the browser markup. With style="display:none", then the control. is not seen, but is sent and becomes part of the browser markup. However, given that you state this works on page load, the the control looks to be part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) lets you do exactly one thing: Trigger a browser dialog that warns the user about potential data loss and allows them to abandon the step that exits from the page.

You cannot produce this dialog yourself with `confirm`, much less can you trigger further actions like clicking a button.

To save a page before the user (accidentally?) closes it, consider using the [`pagehide` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event) like so:

```js
window.onpagehide = function() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/savepage", "information about the page");
};
```

where `/savepage` is a POST endpoint that receives a plain text body containing information about the page.

Comment: pagehide is made for safari and struggles in other browsers. it also only works when you leave a website not when you leave a page so that is no good for my purposes.  In fact trying your code does absolutely nothing on my page-- it doesnt even go into the function -- tested it by using alerts